# Как лучше сохранить коннект Service

Tags: java, android, android-service, callback, android-bundle

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сохранить `Service`, а точнее ссылку на `Service` и присоединённый из основного `Activity` в `Service` `Callback`? Это мне приходится делать из-за того что при смене ориентации экрана `Activity` создаётся заново и естественно все переменные обнуляются и ссылка на мой Service :(

Собственно вот фрагмент отвечающий за `Service` в `Activity` :

```
Intent intent;
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    intent = new Intent(this, Sservice.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        Sservice.LocalBinder binder = (Sservice.LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
        mService.setReciever(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

А это у меня код отвечающий за сохранение данных в `Bundle` для последующего извлечения при завершении поворота экрана.

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    boolean saved = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("connected");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("connected",mService.connected);
    //savedInstanceState. Вот тут я хотел запихнуть в Bundle ссылку на сервис
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Вот это у меня `Callback` срабатывающий из сервиса (на удивление рабочий) :

```
Sservice.ResponseCallback response;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    instance = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

    response = new Sservice.ResponseCallback() {
        public void response(String response) {

            Log.i("Ура ура","Ok");

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `onSaveInstanceState`: в нем сохраните ссылку на сервис.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?